# mamba exec raises CommandNotFoundError: No command 'conda exec' in GitLab CI

Tags: conda, gitlab-ci-runner, mamba

I'm trying to execute

```
mamba exec quarto render --execute --to html --output-dir public
```

using GitLab self-hosted CI and I'm getting

```
CommandNotFoundError: No command 'conda exec'.
```

I already patched the `PATH` environment variable. Why `conda exec` is not fund?

Comment: Where did you find that command? That looks like `docker exec` - I've never seen `mamba exec` before.

Comment: It is `mamba run` instead of `mamba exec`.